# i cant install ros electric

Tags: ros, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ! i have problem . i cant install ros electric . i have ububntu 14.05 .

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full

i have this error :
you have held broken package

i cant fix this error.
please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243144/i-cant-install-ros-electric/) by [hosein_hyper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27843/hosein_hyper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated on the [Electric Install page for Ubuntu](http://wiki.ros.org/electric/Installation/Ubuntu), the apt packages for ROS Electric was only supported on Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10.

ROS Electric is no longer supported, so there are no updates or bug fixes for it.

You should probably install a newer version of ROS, or if you really need Electric you can try to build it from source or install a compatible version of Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0